# How can I unit test AuthControllerIntegrationTest and mock JwtDecoder in Spock correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, integration-testing, spock

I have a spring security Book store api which is working as expected.

My Security Config class look like this.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder () {
        return JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation("https://jwt-issuer-location")
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, '/api/auth/**')
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, '/api/books').authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, '/api/users').authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    InMemoryUserDetailsManagerService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder().username("bob").password("password123").roles("api").build()
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user)
    }
}
```

For controller integrations like returning the list of users and books, I have used `@MockBean` for JwtDecoder like following

```java
@MockBean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder
```

then the test works.

However, for my integration test for authentication, it does not work in the same way. The integration looks like this

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutocConfigureMockMvc
class AuthController extends Specification {
  MockMvc mockMvc

  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext context

  def setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).apply(springSecurity()).build()
  }

  def "401 Unauthorized Exception"() {
    given: 
    String url = "/api/books"

    when:
    ResultActions res = this.mockMvc.perform(get(url))  

    then: 
    response.andExpect(status().is4xxClientError()) 
  }
}
```

For some reason, this auth controller integration test tries to make a http request for verifying the token sent by the user. the url is passed to `jwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation` function.

I believe that is not an ideal way of make a unit test. It is not supposed to make any request to 3rd party

And since this is just the unit test, I passed some random url (I do not want to pass actual url for security purpose and push it. For the production app, I am pulling the actual url from environment variable).

Because of that, when mockMvc.perform runs, it throws `I/O error on GET request for .....`

I do not understand why other integration works by `MockBean` annotation on JwtDecoder. But it does not resolve AuthControllerIntegrationTest error.

Can someone tell I how I should mock the JwtDecoder instead?

Thank you in advance :)

I have tried adding MockBean on JwtDecoder but it does not work for AuthControllerIntegrationTest.
I would like to know how to mock the JwtDecoder correctly or maybe how to mock the JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation. But I do not know how to mock and return what.

Comment: Why do you manually create `mockMvc` when you already have `@AutocConfigureMockMvc`?

Comment: I missed that actually. Thank you. I removed the annotation. The test still failed thou

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking, are you trying to do a unit test and mock `JwtDecoder` or are you trying to make an integration test and not mock it, or something in between?